# How to include CSS file in Mako?

Tags: css, pylons, mako

I'm using Mako template for a project. How can I add a CSS file in Mako?

I try to use `<link type="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%include file='test.css' />" />` in the `<head>` tag, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "doesn't work"?  Is there an error (if so, what)?  What source code is generated?

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
${css_link('/css/filename.css', 'screen')}
```

Source: http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Including+CSS+And+Javascript+(etc.)+In+A+Flexible+Way+With+Mako

Complete example code:

```
<% self.seen_css = set() %>
<head>
    ${self.css()}
</head>

<%def name="css_link(path, media='')">
    % if path not in self.seen_css:
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${path|h}" media="${media}"></link>
    % endif
    <% self.seen_scripts.add(path) %>
</%def>

<%def name="css()">
    ${css_link('/css/main.css', 'screen')}
    ${css_link('/css/navigation.css', 'screen')}
    ${css_link('/css/forms-buttons.css', 'screen')}
    ${css_link('/css/orders.css', 'screen')}
</%def>
```

Comment: can you please ellaborate the answer